# How do I work with the Bluebird error handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

## Introduction

This question aims to, eventually, resolve a problem I'm having in development with Bluebird. However, I'm also using the opportunity to get some things clarified, so there will be side-questions. I also apologize in advance for any feelings of confusion or boredom you might experience while reading the story to come.

---

## Questions

As far as my understanding goes, Bluebird attempts to intelligently catch ignored rejections, according to the following strategy:

> The second approach, which is what bluebird by default takes, is to call a registered handler if a rejection is unhandled by the start of a second turn.
>   -- [Bluebird Readme # Error Handling](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling)

Now herein lies the first side-question: **What does "the start of a second turn" mean?**

Later in the same section, the following is documented:

> Of course this is not perfect, if your code for some reason needs to swoop in and attach error handler to some promise after the promise has been hanging around a while then you will see annoying messages. In that case you can use the .done() method to signal that any hanging exceptions should be thrown.
>   -- [Bluebird Readme # Error Handling](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#error-handling)

Now, I believe that I ran in to the situation described above with my use case being as follows:

- I call a function which will provide me the promise to which I attach a `.catch()`:

  ```
  lib.loadUrls()
  .catch(function(e){console.log(e);});
  ```
- Internally, that function loads content from URL1 and based on the content, loads content from URL2 in sequence:

  ```
  lib.loadUrls =
    return this.loadUrl1()
    .then(this.loadUrl2.bind(this))
  ```
- If the second promise in this chain is rejected the error is handled by the catch *first*, and then by Bluebirds `Possibly unhandled error` handler as well.

This last behavior is unwanted and I can not figure out why it's doing this. So question two could be: **Why, despite an error handler being attached and executed, does Bluebird still consider the possibility of the error being "unhandled"?**

I'm thinking, apparently the promise "has been hanging around for a while" by the time the rejection propagates to the `.catch()`. In which case I should solve it (according to the quoted documentation) by "using the `.done()`".

Now, I've tried several things, but I can't quite figure out how to "use the .done" in this scenario. (It doesn't help that `.done()` returns undefined, preventing me from `.finally`-ing.)

So this introduces my third, and fourth questions: **How do I use `.done()` in this scenario,** and **how do I explicitly conclude a promise-chain, but still attach a `.finally()`**

**EDIT 1:** I've created some JSFiddles to reproduce the bug:

- [Using Bluebird 1.0.5](http://jsfiddle.net/wUhZU/1/) reproduces the bug.
- [Using the latest Bluebird.js](http://jsfiddle.net/wUhZU/2/) reproduces the bug (at this time)
- [Using Beta version 0.10.0-1](http://jsfiddle.net/wUhZU/3/) **does not** reproduce the bug.

**EDIT 2:** The dev [fixed](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/commit/73afa4ae5f89162fc366e74e0219651ee8c5cde9) the bug.

Comment: Please show the full callee and caller function bodies

Comment: I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUhZU/2/) reproducing the bug. When opening the page, you'll see the error is handled by the error handler, and then handled by the unhandled error handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was indeed just a regression bug in bluebird and is now fixed.

The bit about needing to use `.done()` is pretty much theoretical, you won't run in a situation in practice where you would need to attach error handlers in such a way that would cause false positives to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely Bluebird bug, as *handled* error should not be reported (assuming you properly handle promises in `loadUrls` body). So probably you should report it to Bluebird issue tracker.

Concerning `done`, it's pure access function that's best if used instead of `then` or `catch` when you just process resolved value.

It's good to treat `done` as first choice function and use `then` and `catch` only if you really need transformation to other promise, with such approach you also don't need to rely on buggy errors monitoring (best to turn it off completely).

In your case `done` should be used as:

```
lib.loadUrls().done(); // eventual error will be thrown
```

and if for some reason you want to handle error specifically (e.g. in running server you don't  want it throw) do:

```
lib.loadUrls().done(null, function (error) {
  // handle error
});
```

EDIT:

Just noticed, that you still want to process promise returned by `lib.loadUrls().catch(..)` with `finally`. In such case `done` is not a solution. `done` should only be used as final call, but you can combine it with `finally` as follows:

```
lib.loadUrls().finally(function () {
  // cleanup
}).done();
```

Comment: Thanks! `done` And `finally` are clear for me now. You're probably right about it being a bug, seeing as when I do: `lib.loadUrls().catch(handleError).done()`... `handleError` gets called. No exception is thrown by `done` and _then still_ Bluebird handles it as "possibly unhandled" afterwards. Could you clarify one last thing for me. When does the "start of a second turn" occur? Maybe with increased understanding of what's actually happening I can make a better bug-report.

Comment: Have a look at the JSFiddles I edited into my question.