# Is there a replacement for the deprecated deferred.callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

### The problem

I find that the following, fairly verbose pattern commonly arises in my code, when I include libraries that give me objects that are difficult to `promisify`:

```
var object = crummyLibrary.create();
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  object.method('foo', function(err, bar){
    if(err){
      reject(err);
    }else{
      resolve(bar);
    }
  });
});
```

This used to be less verbose with `Promise.defer()`:

```
var deferred = Promise.defer();
object.method('foo', deferred.callback);
return deferred.promise;
```

But that's deprecated now (for good reason) but I haven't found a nice replacement for this pattern. I know there's this:

```
return Promise.promisify(object.method, object)('foo');
```

But it feels hacky and fiddely because of the passing around of `context`/`receiver`.

### What I'm looking for

I'm hoping for something that replaces the old `deferred.callback`, maybe along the lines of:

```
var promise = new Promise;
object.method('foo', promise.callback);
return promise;
```

Or possibly:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject, callback){
  object.method('foo', callback);
});
```

Or alternatively, someone who points out to me that I've been "doing it wrong" all along.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed but Petka (Esailija) has added `Promise.fromNode` to the library for your use case - by all means that's what you should be using in your case.

Comment: I have noticed. See our conversation below Esailija's answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from 2.9.0 Bluebird ships with a `.fromNode` method for faster dynamic promisification for badly behaved libraries:

```
Promise.fromNode(object.method.bind(object, "foo"))
```

---

I suppose something like the following can be implemented:

```
return Promise.fromNodeFunction(function(callback){
  object.method('foo', callback);
});
```

Just need to think better name that is not as verbose...

To implement it yourself:

```
Promise.fromNodeFunction = function(resolver) {
    var d = Promise.defer();
    try {
        resolver(d.callback);
    } catch (e) {
        d.reject(e);
    }
    return d.promise;
};
```

This is most preferable because it is 3 lines now but with arrow functions it's a one liner:

```
return Promise.fromNodeFunction(callback => object.method("foo", callback))
```

It also works pretty well with bind:

```
return Promise.fromNodeFunction(object.method.bind(object, "foo"))
```

Comment: his whole point was to avoid .defer() since someone deprecated it (for a good reason):P

Comment: Your idea is interesting, though your implementation ironically uses `Promise.defer`. I think I will use this solution though (using a better implementation that I'll then edit into your answer).

Comment: excuse me for asking here, but could you look and possibly answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114180/if-some-function-is-not-optimized-does-it-mean-that-all-functions-where-it-is-de  ? I saw a link to the https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers in your profile, may be even you are the author of this article

Comment: @Avaq bluebird 2.9.0 has [`Promise.fromNode`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisefromnodefunction-resolver---promise)

Comment: @Esailija Oh that's perfect then! :D Was this introduced as a result of my question/your answer, or do great minds simply think alike? I'll accept your answer for this comment alone because it's essentially the same thing. A little lame though that [my edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6819265) because now we're stuck to `Promise.defer()` for the "polyfill" which misses the point.

Comment: I just noticed that it's *my* example code in the docs. I feel honored. This is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845515/how-do-i-work-with-the-bluebird-error-handler) I've contributed to Bluebird through a Stack Overflow question. Oh and I've also just realized you are Petka. Whoops. I guess you were in your full right using `Promise.defer` I'll shut my mouth now. :$

Comment: @Avaq yes I don't know about any library that doesn't expose classes (and didn't want to use one that does expose e.g. `'fs'`, since it would set a bad example) so I just used yours :D

Comment: A real-world example is the fairly popular [email-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/email-templates#basic). As you can see in the basic example, calling `emailTemplates` gives you a `template` function which you need to call with a nodeback.

Answer (score 1):

Well, promisify is meant to be called once when your app initializes. You can use `promisifyAll` to turn whole APIs to promisified APIs at once.

```
Promise.promisifyAll(app.auth);
```

Which would let you use any method as a promise-returning method on `app.auth` any time later in your application:

```
app.auth.authenticateAsync("local").then(function(res){ // preserves context
    // handle result
});
```

Also note that `promisify` and `promisifyAll` are significantly faster than using `new Promise` and promisifying yourself because they utilize dynamic recompilation techniques and other various optimization so it is best to use them (but only at initialization time).

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for the answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I use `promisifyAll` on anything possible, but sometimes libraries give me objects that they haven't exposed a constructor or prototype (think: `function(){return {...}}`). It's in these cases that I need on-the-fly promisification. My apologies for not having specified this in my question. I will edit it in.

Comment: In that case no - there is no direct replacement to the pattern you were using. You can keep using `.defer()` for a while and when/if it is removed you can shim it.